# Copying an array of Object Pointers

Tags: c++

What would be the correct way to copy an array of pointers pointing to a certain object into another object through the constructor?

Assuming that:

```cpp
// ClassA.h

class ClassA {
  ClassB** m_classBs{};
public:
  ClassA(const ClassB* classBs[], size_t cnt);
}
```

```cpp
ClassA::ClassA(const ClassB* classBs[], size_t cnt) {
  m_classBs = new ClassB*[cnt]
  for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    m_classBs[i] = &classBs[i];
    // I have tried here using *m_classBs[i] = &classBs[I];
    // and a lot of variations but neither seems to work for me 
    // at the moment. I am trying to copy the array of pointers
    // from classBs[] (parameter in the constructor) to m_classBs
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `m_classBs[i] = classBs[i];`? Did you allocate memory for `m_classBs`? Is there a reason to use C-arrays?

Comment: @jabaa Yes, but I get an error saying `Assigning to 'm_classBs *' from 'const m_classBs *' discards qualifiers`. The constructor's declaration was provided to me, so I'm not allowed to remove the `const` from it.

Comment: @jabaa Sorry, forgot first line in the constructor that says `m_classBs = new ClassB*[cnt]`

Comment: Now, you're allocating memory in a loop, causing memory leaks.

Comment: `std::vector<const ClassB*>`.

Comment: Change `ClassB** m_classBs{};` to `const ClassB** m_classBs{};`

Comment: if you use `std::vector<const ClassB*> m_classBs;`as suggested,  the body of your constructor becomes `std::copy(classBs, classBs+cnt, std::back_inserter(m_classBs));`, and that's it.

Comment: @jabaa Thanks! That sounds like it would do the trick! But now, when allocating memory, I get `Assigning to 'const sdds::Reservation **' from 'sdds::Reservation **' discards qualifiers in nested pointer types`, I'm guessing this is because as it is `const` now I can't change it's size?

Comment: I wrote you a working solution: https://godbolt.org/z/Warv6E5a6

Comment: @jabaa Thank you so very much! I wasn't aware that I could do `m_classBs = new const ClassB*[cnt];` Appreciate it a lot! 
@PeteBecker and @WhozCraig thanks a lot for the ideas but sadly I am not allowed (or have been taught) to use vectors

Comment: @SebastianRubina Without knowing what `ClassB` is, or what `ClassA` is supposed to do with the `ClassB` objects (take ownership of them? Make copies of them?), it is difficult to answer this question accurately. The first thought that ran through my head when I saw the code was the "clone idiom", but that may or may not apply to your situation. There is just not enough info provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use use the correct type:

```
class ClassA {
  const ClassB** m_classBs;
public:
  ClassA(const ClassB* classBs[], size_t cnt);
  ~ClassA() { delete[] ClassB; }
};

ClassA::ClassA(const ClassB* classBs[], size_t cnt) : m_classBs(new const ClassB*[cnt]) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    m_classBs[i] = classBs[i];
  }
}
```

I prefer to completely avoid `new` whenever possible:

```
class ClassA {
  std::vector<const ClassB*> m_classBs;
public:
  ClassA(const ClassB* classBs[], size_t cnt);
};

ClassA::ClassA(const ClassB* classBs[], size_t cnt) : m_classBs(cnt) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    m_classBs[i] = classBs[i];
  }
}
```